# How to pass a multi-select array of values to mvc3 controller action via $.get?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery

How do I send back an array of values back to a controller action via $.get?

I have tried (string[] values) and (List).

```
     ...
     var val = $('#CStatus').val();  // Get a list of selected values
     alert(val);   // Displays 0,1
            $.get('@Url.Action("GO")', {  junk: val }, function (data) {
                $('#gridview').html(data);
            });


    public ActionResult GO(List<String> junk /* or string[] junk or string junk*/)
    {
        // junk is null!
    }
```

Comment: when you say "get a list of selected values" is this a CSV string? What is the JS structure of `val`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following was even failing

```
  $.post('@Url.Action("GO")', { 'values': [1,2,3]}, function (data) {
      ...
  });
```

But this fixed it:

```
jQuery.ajaxSettings.traditional = true;
```

[Here](http://www.dovetailsoftware.com/blogs/kmiller/archive/2010/02/24/jquery-1-4-breaks-asp-net-mvc-actions-with-array-parameters) is a good [article](http://www.dovetailsoftware.com/blogs/kmiller/archive/2010/02/24/jquery-1-4-breaks-asp-net-mvc-actions-with-array-parameters) describing the issue.

With the following Controller ActionResult Sig:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult GO(string[] values)
{
    // junk is no longer null!
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your val is a comma-separated list of integers. If this can always be guaranteed as the input, you could simply explode() that string in your action (using comma as the delimiter). This will give you a nice array of the selected values to work with.

Comment: It's actually an array of values but I do like your idea!